# how to get all attributes' values from html using regex

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeWork.css">
    <script src="./homeWork.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='mango'> first div mango</div>
        <div type='red' class='m2ango'>div red m2ango</div>
        <div type='green' class='magngo'>div green magngo</div>
        <li class='mango'>li mango
    </div>
    <div class='mango'>second div mango</div>
    <li type='green' class='mango'>li green mango
        </div>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

this is my HTML file and I want to get all of the attributes' values,
class: container
class: mango
type: red
class:m2ngo
type: green
class: magngo
class: mango
class:mango
......

Comment: In what format?

Comment: while loop with a regex i guess.

Comment: In javascript or typescript

Comment: how can I run on all the body elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
targetString:string | any = '<div class="AAAAA>A</div>'
const rExp : RegExp = /<([^> ]+)([^>]*)>/;
const matches = targetString.match(rExp) 
console.log(matches[2]);
```